# How to get count of articles in sub-sub-categories with MediaWiki API

Tags: python, api, mediawiki, wikipedia

I want to generate an xml/json that displays the category info (count of pages and subcats) for all **sub-subcategories** in a specific category in Wikipedia. This requires me to parse through 2 levels in the data hierarchy, as in category > list of subcategories > list of sub-subcategories > display number of articles per sub-subcategory.

Using wikipedia API, this gives me what I'm looking for one level of subcategories:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:People_by_nationality_and_occupation&gcmlimit=30&gcmprop=ids|title&prop=categoryinfo&continue=

Here's the script I'm running, which gives me dictionaries of sub-sub-categories, but I can't get page counts (categoryinfo) to show. How can I fix this?

```
from wikitools import wiki, category, api

def get_category_members (category_name, depth, lang='en'):

articles = {}
if depth < 0:
    return articles

#Begin crawling articles in category
results = wikipedia_query({'list':'categorymembers',
                               'cmtitle': category_name,
                               'cmtype' : 'subcat',
                               'cmlimit': '300',
                               'action' : 'query',
                               'prop' : 'categoryinfo'}, lang)
return results
if 'categorymembers' in results.keys() and len(results['categorymembers']) > 0:
    for i, page in enumerate(results['categorymembers']):
        article = {page['title'] : 'categoryinfo'} 
        articles.update(article)
    return articles
```

Comment: You will have to iterate through categories, and count. Note that there is nothing that prevents a category from containing its parent, so make sure you have some mechanism to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: @leo I added my script which iterates over a dictionary of sub-sub-categories, but how can I get the page counts to display as value?

Comment: It should all be in `categoryinfo`: `{"size":16,"pages":0,"files":0,"subcats":16}` means 0 pages, 0 files, 16 subcategories, for a total of 16 objects. Just count the pages (and files, if you want them too)

Comment: @leo exactly, but I can't get that to show with the code above..

Answer (score 2):

If this is for a Wikimedia project like Wikipedia, it's probably easier to rely on Magnus Manske's category recursion tools, like [catscan](https://tools.wmflabs.org/catscan2/catscan2.php) (see [code logic](https://bitbucket.org/magnusmanske/magnustools/src/d1a20f3dfabc5bdf476275b3c257f7a30e04ea6d/public_html/php/common.php?at=master#cl-120).

As far as I can see, your code doesn't create a Wiki object, nor an APIRequest, nor it iterates in subcategories recursively. See an example where I used [categorymembers as generator](https://github.com/hay/wiki-tools/blob/663cc97e07f7ac0a79c47db5e22e349659471275/etc/mediacounts-stats.py#L106) for extracting more information on category members (not recursively in subcategories, though).